# closing unclear questions - which close reason to use and when?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, scope

With the latest changes to the close reasons, there are two close reasons that sound very similar to me, and in going through the Close Votes queue, I can't seem to find any rhyme or reason to when which is chosen, and often both seem to be chosen.

> **unclear what you're asking**
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

and

> **off-topic because...**
>
> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Both of these seem to boil down to "You haven't provided enough information, so we don't know how to answer your question. Please provide more information."

**Is there some guidance somewhere on what differentiates these two close reasons? Perhaps some canonical questions to fit the mold of each of them would best illustrate the intended differences would work best.**

Also, it possible to clarify the differences between these in the 'close reasons' dialog to make the difference more clear?

Note: The ["Recent changes to close reasons on Stack Overflow" question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow) highlights one of the new reasons ("unclear what you're asking"), but doesn't really answer this as there is no direct comparison to the other close reason, which may be a source of confusion for which to use when...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"unclear what you're asking" is for questions where you just can't figure out what the asker is trying to say, either as a consequence of poor language skills on the asker's part, or just plain vagueness in the question.

An egregious, yet depressingly everyday example (that I made up but could very well be a real, existing question!):

> ### close the sql query
>
> how to close the query?
>
> SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = 'bar' LIMIT 10
>
> i call the query but how i close the query?
>
> [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close)

For starters, what does "close the query" mean? The question keeps repeating this nonsensical phrase over and over again, but no amount of repetition is going to clarify what it actually means.

And then there's the tags. Aside from the filler [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close) tag, unless you're working with some sort of hybrid database technology, you're probably working with *either* MySQL *or* SQL Server, but not both at the same time or in the same instance. If you aren't even paying attention to which database technology you're using to figure out how to tag your question... maybe that's where the problem really lies.

In general, if you find yourself having to ask "What do you/does X mean?", then it's probably "unclear what you're asking".

---

The off-topic reason can be used for questions that are well-articulated and have clear descriptions of what is happening, and simply lack crucial information that is required to be answered. If a question says "It doesn't work", chances are it'll fall under this category if the rest of it is clear enough. Another common example is when the code is incomplete (that's where the "[include a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" guidance applies).

Here's an example which might help you recover from the one above:

> ### Unable to submit PHP contact form
>
> I have a contact form, which looks like this:
>
> ```html
> <!--
> This code block might only include a tiny fragment of the contact form,
> e.g. only one input field, or only the opening <form> tag, or similar.
> -->
> ```
>
> When I submit it, I get an error, and I see a blank screen. How do I fix this?
>
> [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) [contact-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contact-form)

The question makes it clear, from its title, description and tags, that:

- The asker has an HTML contact form with a PHP backend.
- The asker is unable to get their contact form to submit properly. Presumably some output is to be expected, because the asker mentions seeing a blank screen and is implying that the blank screen must be an error state rather than the expected result.

But the question also has a number of glaring problems:

- The HTML snippet may be incomplete.
- It says that the contact form is written in PHP, but no PHP code is shown (except maybe for a handful of template tags within the HTML that don't add very much to the problem statement).
- It says that an error is encountered but the error message isn't shown. But it also says that the output is blank. Either the question is contradicting itself, or the asker is seeing the error message elsewhere such as in an error log, but in either case the problem remains that the error message isn't given in the question.

Without the code and/or the error message, there's no way of knowing what the exact problem is and therefore there's no way to answer the question of how to fix the problem, even though the average reader can make sense of what is happening.

I'm all for clarifying each close reason in the close dialog. I doubt it'd benefit the asker greatly because many askers simply don't bother to read the close descriptions, but it would certainly help close voters make a more informed decision on when to use which close reason.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock - this is exactly the kind of guidance I was looking for.  As for the dialog part, I was imagining it would be something more for the benefit of the close voters, since they seemed to be used interchangeably by some voters. I imagine I'll be using this as a reference for a while to keep the concepts clear.