# Shall we close as unclear a question where OP simply failed to say that he could not compile?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I had a negative feeling at seeing obvious beginner's questions containing short code with trivial errors closed as unclear. Examples https://stackoverflow.com/q/42930448/3545273 or [Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42693049/3545273) - I've edited the first one to make it closer to SO rules and see whether it is enough to have it re-opened

Both are far from nice questions, and very far from canonical questions on interesting or corner case questions for language lawyers. They are just questions where a beginner have just falled into a common error and ask for help in order to fix it.

We may decide that we do not want trivial questions here, but the close reason IMHO is not fair. A new user will not be able to understand what is unclear in his question: he/she tries to write a short program to do a simple task, gets a compile error and do not know how to fix. What is *unclear* here? Off topic because the error message is not present in the question would at least be more educative, but my opinion is that *unclear* just show that we do not want to have anything to do with beginners.

So my question is: is it correct to close as unclear a question containing short code, a *description* of a simple task that the program should do but not the compilation error message?

Comment: The message links to [ask], which contains many, many tips on asking a good question, including that you need to specify the error message. I expect they are duplicates as well, if they are common errors, so perhaps a better use of time is to search for those...

Comment: Not a lot of people want SO to be a debugging service for people who don't know how or are too lazy to do it.  Kicking those folks in the rear is better than spoon feeding them.  Also they are typically asked by the kind of user that doesn't show consideration for others (and are therefore more likely to delete after getting an answer, less likely to respond to feedback or select an answer as correct, etc).

Comment: Other details on close reasons can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256521/3545273)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Both are far from nice questions

Since you realize that they're bad questions, you should make sure to downvote them, to accurately reflect that fact for other potential readers.

> A new user will not be able to understand what is unclear in his question

Then by all means, post a comment to try to help them understand how they can fix their question.

That said, at the end of the day it is *their* responsibility to post a suitable question, not anyone else's.  Other people may choose to help, if they would like to, but if a question is unclear it merits being closed as unclear.   We don't refuse to close unclear questions just because the author is incapable of clarifying them (in fact, it tends to be *more* important in such situations).

> A new user will not be able to understand what is unclear in his question: he/she tries to write a short program to do a simple task, gets a compile error and do not know how to fix.

That the person is a new user doesn't mean that they can't ask a clear question.  *Millions* of people have managed to ask a clear question on SE as a new user.  It's not *that* hard, and the site provides *lots* of resources to help people understand how to ask appropriate questions.

> What is unclear here?

Well, for starters, not describing what the actual problem that they have is, not clearly describing what the program should be doing, what it's actually doing, and how they differ, not describing what research they've done into these types of errors to see how others have solved them, not describing the various things that they tried to do to solve the problem, and how these various attempts failed, etc.

> Off topic because the error message is not present in the question would at least be more educative

You can think of that close reason as basically being a sub-set of "unclear", and it is of course the close reason that's being used on your second example.  You're correct that, when it's applicable, it's somewhat more informative than the broader "unclear" reason.  It's not really worth reopening and re-closing though, and I'm not even sure that that would make sense here, as that's not the only thing causing a lack of clarity.  You might consider posting the information that that close reason provides in a comment though, as it would help address *some* of the problems in the question.

> is it correct to close as unclear a question containing short code, a description of a simple task that the program should do but not the compilation error message?

Well in this case the task that it's actually supposed to do sure doesn't seem clear to me, but yes, it is "unclear" to just post some code, a description of what a program is supposed to do, and to say, "it doesn't work" without any description of *why* it doesn't work.

Comment: Fine for me. When I started flagging questions, I had disputed or rejected flags for questions lacking research that I wanted to close for that reason, so I (wrongly) assumed that poor questions not falling in one of the explicit close reasons were fine here. I'll be more strict from now on... But even if I admit the English is not my first language, and I often miss the precise meaning of some expressions, I really think that newcomers simply cannot understand why their question is closed and just think that SO is unfriendly for beginners.